# Inserting a value into a linked list in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linked-list

I am having trouble using linked list in Ruby. In the method `insert_node`, if `head` is not `nil` then `current_node.next = _node` will get the value to be inserted at the end of the linked list. I don't understand how `head` is being updated with the value added to the end of the linked list. To me it seems that `current_node` is a copy of `head` and then after the until loop `current_node.next` gets the value to be inserted. Just by looking at it I thought that `head` will be the same previous linked list without the added value assuming head is not `nil`.

```
class Node 
  attr_accessor :data, :next

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data 
    @next = nil 
  end
end

class List

  def insert_node(head, value)
    _node = Node.new(value)

    if head.nil?
      return _node
    end

    current_node = head 
    until current_node.next.nil?
      current_node = current_node.next
    end

    current_node.next = _node
    head
  end

  def display(head)
    temp = head 
    while temp 
      print "#{temp.data} "
      temp = temp.next
    end
  end

end

obj = List.new
head = nil

head = obj.insert_node(head, 1)
head = obj.insert_node(head, 2)
obj.display(head)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `insert` function here works because `current_node.next = _node` is a permanent modification to an object in the list that is pointed to by `head`. After this call, even though `current_node` is garbage collected (it's just a temporary pointer), the node that it was pointing to during the `current_node.next = _node` line has had its `.next` property permanently modified.

Here's a diagram of adding the new node `3` to the list `1->2->nil`:

```
(before the `until` loop)

+---------+   +---------+
| data: 1 |   | data: 2 |   
| next: ----> | next: ----> [nil]
+---------+   +---------+
  ^    ^
  |    |
head  current_node
```

```
(after the `until` loop; `current_node.next == nil`)
(and before `current_node.next = _node`)

+---------+   +---------+
| data: 1 |   | data: 2 |   
| next: ----> | next: ----> [nil]
+---------+   +---------+
     ^             ^
     |             |
   head        current_node
```

```
(after `current_node.next = _node`)

+---------+   +---------+   +---------+
| data: 1 |   | data: 2 |   | data: 3 |   
| next: ----> | next: ----> | next: ----> [nil]
+---------+   +---------+   +---------+
     ^             ^
     |             |
   head        current_node
```

Incidentally, this `insert` method exhibits poor design; every insertion is an O(n) linear time operation requiring traversal of the entire list. An improved `LinkedList` class design would offer a `tail` pointer, allowing O(1) constant time insertion to the end of the list. Alternately, the class could offer `add_front()` without a tail pointer, which would set `new_head.next = old_head` and `head = new_head`.

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question. I also am aware that I should offer a tail pointer and I will implement that next as I was just testing some code out.